# html file content evaluates to non-empty in empty lines

Tags: php, arrays

I have an html file, ISO-8859-1, I handle its content as an array and I would like to find empty rows (empty values), but no matter what I do, the value always evaluates to non-empty, however I don't see any content in some of the rows. I think maybe it's because the different encoding, or maybe because it's a different encoding AND an array at the same time, but I can't find what is wrong.
if I change encoding in notepad++, empty rows remain still empty. if I turn on show all hidden characters, there is only CRLF. is it possible that it doesn't evaluate empty because of CRLF??

```
$content = file($filename);

1. row: <tr ...
2. row:
3. row: <tr> ...

foreach ($content as $key => $value) {
    if (!empty($value)) {
        echo 'not empty!';
    }
}
```

everywhere is echoed 'not empty!' in row nr. 2 also (what seems to be empty).
in fact, I wasn't even able to search in this array (with array_search).
what is happening here?
thanks a lot!

Comment: In this case isset will always return true since the variable exists try using empty($value) or trim($value) == ""

Comment: empty() also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$content = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

so you do not get the newlines.
Or if you want to have only the not-empty lines, use

```
$content = file($filename, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

Comment: thanks, but I need those empty lines, because I have to calculate with them, and this still doesn't solve the array_search() problem.

Comment: Did you try FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES and changing isset() to !empty() ?

Comment: ohh sorry, it seems to be the solution. so it means CRLF is the problem in such cases?

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation for [`isset()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

> Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL.

Your variable `$value` exists but is an empty string and not `null`.

Try `empty()` instead or just use `trim()`, because an empty string will also evaluate to `false`:

```
foreach ($content as $key => $value) {
    if (trim($value)) {
        echo 'not empty!';
    }
}
```